# Merge and Overwrite Two or More Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, overwrite, array-merge

How to merge and overwrite multidimensional array with same key and value with array_merge_recursive ? Supposed I Have two array like below:

```
$arr1 = array(       
   // OVERWRITE
   array('prop_id' => 1, 'prop_value' => 'batman'),
   array('prop_id' => 2, 'prop_value' => 'ironman'),
   // NOT OVERWRITE
   array('prop_id' => 5, 'prop_value' => 'wonderwoman'),
);

$arr2 = array(
   array('prop_id' => 1, 'prop_value' => 'robin'),
   array('prop_id' => 2, 'prop_value' => 'superman'),
   array('prop_id' => 4, 'prop_value' => 'catwoman'),
);
```

I want to merge and overwrite it with new value (the rule is comparison key with the same value it not overwrite), the expected result is

```
 $result = array_merge_overwrite($arr1, $arr2, array('prop_id') /* Comparison Key */);
 $result = array(       
   array('prop_id' => 1 /* Comparison Key */, 'prop_value' => 'robin' /* Comparison value */),
   array('prop_id' => 2, 'prop_value' => 'superman'),
   array('prop_id' => 4, 'prop_value' => 'catwoman'),
   array('prop_id' => 5, 'prop_value' => 'wonderwoman'),
);
```

With array_merge_recursive it appended not overwrited, I try with array_replace_recursive like below:

```
$result = array_replace_recursive(
    array(
       1 => array('prop_id' => 1, 'prop_value' => 'batman'),
       2 => array('prop_id' => 2, 'prop_value' => 'ironman'),
       5 => array('prop_id' => 5, 'prop_value' => 'wonderwoman'),
    ),
    array(
       1 => array('prop_id' => 1, 'prop_value' => 'robin'),
       2 => array('prop_id' => 2, 'prop_value' => 'superman'),
       4 => array('prop_id' => 4, 'prop_value' => 'catwoman'),
    ),
);
```

It works, but my code look nasty and dirty. Any better solution than mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that would work as you described:

```
function array_merge_overwrite($arr1, $arr2, $uniques=array('prop_id'), $delimiter='-')
{
    $result = array();
    $uk = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $a1)
    {   
        $uk = array();
        foreach($uniques as $u) $uk[] = $a1[$u];
        $result[implode($delimiter, $uk)] = $a1;
    }   

    foreach($arr2 as $a2)
    {   
        $uk = array();
        foreach($uniques as $u) $uk[] = $a2[$u];
        $result[implode($delimiter, $uk)] = $a2;
    }   
    return $result;
}
```

If passed `$arr1` and `$arr2` as defined in the question, the above function will return an array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [prop_id] => 1
            [prop_value] => robin
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [prop_id] => 2
            [prop_value] => superman
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [prop_id] => 5
            [prop_value] => wonderwoman
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [prop_id] => 4
            [prop_value] => catwoman
        )

)
```

Of course, if you were to always and only use `prop_id` as the unique element then the function could be quite a bit simpler:

```
function array_merge_overwrite($arr1, $arr2)
{
    $tmp = array();
    foreach($arr1 as $a1) $tmp[$a1['prop_id']] = $a1['prop_value'];
    foreach($arr2 as $a2) $tmp[$a2['prop_id']] = $a2['prop_value'];
    $result = array();
    foreach($tmp as $k=>$v) $result[] = array('prop_id'=>$k, 'prop_value'=>$v);
    return $result;
}
```

The only difference in the returned array in this later function is that the keys of the element arrays will be the standard numerical values instead of matching the `prop_id`s

Answer (score 0):

As I can see is that you want to preserve the second array elements where in case when key of first array and second array are matching.

PHP manual says that:
**If you want to append array elements from the second array to the first array while not overwriting the elements from the first array and not re-indexing, use the + array union operator:**

```
<?php
$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$result = $array1 + $array2;
var_dump($result);
?>
```

**The keys from the first array will be preserved. If an array key exists in both arrays, then the element from the first array will be used and the matching key's element from the second array will be ignored.**

O/P

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "zero_a"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "two_a"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "three_a"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "one_b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "four_b"
}
```

For more detail look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)